# How to create a sh file to change directory and perform operations

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu-18.04, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to connect to a Linux VM using a `sh` file running in my pipelines in order to create a small CI/CD solution. My idea is to login to the VM and perform a Docker compose down/up operation.

My VM is an Ubuntu 18

This is the code inside the bash file.

```sh
sshpass -p mypassword ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@vmip
cd ~ /folder/subfolder
docker-compose down
docker-compose up
```

I'm trying to run it locally and I get this error:

> nodename nor servname provided, or not known
> : No such file or directoryfolder/subfolder
> No such command: down

Any workaround with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that space between the tilde and the first slash intended? (line 2) Also doesn't seem like you are even connecting with the first line.

Comment: Looks like you have dos line endings in your script. Run your script via `dos2unix` utility and inspect under hex editor, `hexdump -C` or `cat -v`.

Comment: The space is not intended is a typo, didnt realized it thanks! And about the connection line, it is working executed alone. Not sure if it is working when executing in the bash.

Comment: Also note that the commands after `ssh` will run on the _local_ system.  I’d separate out the “run these commands” and “remotely” parts, and do something like `ssh user@vmip ./restart-docker-app`.

Comment: Excellent @DavidMaze . didnt know that commands where run locally. Will try your solution

Comment: I have an update...doing this, sshpass -p mypassword ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "user@vmip" 'cd ~/folder/subfolder; ls; docker ps' my sh file works until the ls.... the docker ps part shows an error saying bash: docker: command not found .... same if I do docker-compose down...... what is after the space is not being recognized as part of the command

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) in your comments. Make sure docker-compose is installed on your VM. Additionally I would suggest you try something along the lines of the following for safety and some feedback for your own sanity.

```
if ! [ -x "$(command -v docker-compose)" ]; then
  echo 'Error: docker-compose is not installed.' >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

The above will ensure you have docker-compose installed before continuing.

Additionally I would suggest doing something along the lines of this to get you feedback and remember the -d for docker-compose up.

```
docker-compose down
echo

docker-compose up -d
echo
```

If you need new instances of your docker containers also don't forget to build them, otherwise you just keep reloading previously built containers, and that might become an issue depending on what you place in them.

```
docker-compose build
echo
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the -d just ensures you don't force the container logs to the current screen/terminal.

Comment: Hi, I do have docker and docker compose installed. Actually the vm already have a working solution there. What I want is to create the CI/CD solution

Comment: hmm, apologies, was not really clear to me from your question.